# Unity3D: Como posso mover GameObjects de mesmo script de forma independente?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Criei um script em Unity3D que faz um `GameObject` se mover de forma senoidal.

O movimento ocorre perfeitamente, mas quando mais de um `GameObject` contendo este script está em cena todos se movem como um espelho um do outro e não de forma relativa, deixando o jogo muito artificial.

Tentei usar posicionamento local e mesmo assim não consegui resolver o problema.

Eis o código:

```
using System.Collections; using System.Collections.Generic; using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy4 : Nave {

 public float horizontalSpeed;
 public int yFactor;
 private float count = 3;
 private Vector3 s;
 private bool setPos = false;
 private float x;
 private float y;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
     x = 0;
     y = 0;
     s = transform.position;
     side = Side.defside.ENEMY;
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
     y += yFactor * Time.deltaTime;
     x = Mathf.Sin (Time.time) * horizontalSpeed;
     transform.position = s + new Vector3 (x,y, 0);
 }

}
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem, mas se você usar um random para o movimento ai cada um vai ter um comportamento um pouco diferente. Dai é com você definir onde vai querer usar o random, se em posicão, velocidade, direção etc....

Answer (score 2):

## Ondas senoidais

Uma onda senoidal tem três propriedades relevantes:

- Frequência - É o inverso da distância entre dois picos de uma onda senoidal.
- Amplitude - É a diferença entre a altura do pico de do vale da onda.
- Fase - É a parte da onda senoidal na qual um objeto que por ela se move está.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que `x` e `y` são dois picos de onda consecutivos, de forma que:

— [a] `x < y`,
— [b] `Mathf.Sin(x) = Mathf.Sin(y) = p`,
— [c] não existe `t` tal que (`x < t < y` e `Mathf.Sin(t) = 1`) e
— [d] para todo `b` real `-a <= Mathf.Sin(b) <= a`.

Assim sendo, a frequência seria dada por `1 / (y - x)`. A amplitude é `2 * a`. A fase é dada por `t` para a expressão `f(t)`, onde `f` é a sua função  senoide (não necessariamente a própria função `sin`, pois `f(x) = 2 * Mathf.Sin(x)` também é uma função senoide).

## Analisando o seu código

Você está usando o seguinte para definir a posição do seu objeto:

```
x = Mathf.Sin (Time.time) * horizontalSpeed;
```

A sua função senoidal no caso é `f(x) = Mathf.Sin (Time.time) * horizontalSpeed`. O `horizontalSpeed` acaba sendo a amplitude. A fase é dada por `Time.time` e a frequência é de *2π segundos*. Isso significa que os seus objetos vão ter uma posição que oscila sempre em ciclos de *2π segundos* e todos estarão sincronizados quanto a fase da onda.

A solução é introduzir alguma coisa que faça com que eles se dessincronizem quanto a fase e quanto a frequência.

Além disso, use `FixedUpdate` ao invés de `Update`. O `FixedUpdate` tem intervalos de tempo consistentes e é útil para atualizar a lógica do jogo, enquanto que o `Update` tem mais o propósito de preparar a renderização na tela.

## Código resultante

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy4 : Nave {

    public float horizontalSpeed;
    public int yFactor;
    public float frequency;
    public float phaseOffset;
    private float count = 3;
    private Vector3 s;
    private bool setPos = false;
    private float x;
    private float y;

    void Start() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        s = transform.position;
        side = Side.defside.ENEMY;
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        y += yFactor * Time.deltaTime;
        x = Mathf.Sin(Time.time * frequency / Mathf.PI + phaseOffset) * horizontalSpeed;
        transform.position = s + new Vector3(x, y, 0);
    }
}
```

O valor de `frequency` vai ser o número de vezes por segundo que você quer que o seu objeto percorra um ciclo completo na onda (e não pode ser zero). O valor do `phaseOffset` define a fase na qual o objeto está quando o tempo for zero. Esses valores, você pode definir um diferente para cada objeto ou colocar algum número aleatório qualquer, de acordo com o que você achar melhor.